# first-child problems with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Show me another way to write so it finds the first A:

```
$("UL.tab LI A.selected, UL.tab LI A:first-child").corner("tl:7px bl:7px");
```

As my Jquery doesnt seem to go for the first A tag!?

**Markup:**

```
<ul class="tabNavigation">
            <li><a href="#Description" class="selected">Description</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Details">Details</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Features">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SpareParts">Spare Parts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Downloads">Downloads</a></li>
          </ul>
```

Comment: Maybe you want to use the `:first` jQuery selector: http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Comment: Show *us* your HTML, and explain which of the elements you want to access and then we'll, happily, show you the selector to use.

Comment: But all anchors are the first children in their LI parent elements...

Comment: what is `ul.tab` you did not provided any explanation for this element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your markup you can use the following selector:

```
$("ul.tabNavigation li:first a").corner("tl:7px bl:7px");
```

Here is better to use `:first` selector for `<li>`, since `<a>` is always the `:first-child` of `<li>`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: maybe you could explain with an answer?

Comment: When you have the option, `:first-child` is a better choice than `:first`. Using `:first-child` instead, that selector can go straight to the speedy `querySelectorAll()` method.

Comment: @VisioN: could you help me here please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259576/first-menu-item-not-being-selected

Answer (score 2):

`$('ul.tab li a.selected :first')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the first ANCHOR element (the one that's inside the first LI element), you can do this:

```
$( 'a:first', '.tabNavigation' )
```

Usually, you want your "main" elements to be available as references throughout your code (so that you don't have to query them repeatedly). For instance you can retrieve the reference to the UL element beforehand:

```
var tabnav = $( '.tabNavigation' )[0];
```

and then when you want to select the first ANCHOR, you do this:

```
$( 'a:first', tabnav )
```

This will perform very well.

Similarly, to select the ANCHOR that has the "selected" class:

```
$( 'a.selected', tabnav )
```