# first menu item not being selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**Problem:**

I have a menu which when you hover on the parent items it should show the first item.
eg when you hover on 'Kayaks & Canoes' it *should* highlight the first item 2+ Person and show the content in the right.

You should also be able to hover on Boats and the content on the right should change. Recreation should be selected by default but you should be able to hover on fishing too.

Currently it doesnt show the first item but you can hover on any item and it will show up.

**What have i tried?**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //on hover of sub menu li then highlight itself
    $('div#new-menu-lower ul.menuul li.menuli').hover(

    function() {

        $(this).children('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul').css("display","block");
        $('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul li ul:first').css("display","block");
        $('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul li').css("display","block");
        $('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul li ul li:first').css("display","block");
        $(this).children('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul li ul').css("display","block");

    }, function() {

        $(this).children('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul').css("display","none");
        $('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul li ul:first').css("display","none");
        $('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul li:first').css("display","none");
        $('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul li ul li:first').css("display","none");
        $(this).children('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul li ul').css("display","none");

    })
});
```

**JSFIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/NDMuu/7/

I'll accept a pure css solution using pseudo class `:hover` IF you can get it to work, otherwise i think Jquery/JS is the way to go?

**EDIT:**updated my description slightly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get the first item to show by default is to use an `if` statement which declares that: if the parent list item is `display: block` then it will also be that. When you hover over another one, you only need to tell the other items to be `display: none`. I don't have the time to fix all your code, but this is where to start. Give that a shot and then I'll help you finish it up.